# Reutilizar numero correlativo

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo un modulo donde creo obtengo el mayor numero para luego aumentar en uno. (este correlativo no es mi ID del producto, sino un correlativo para el cliente) Ejemplo: Contenedor `1` tiene 3 items este correlativo seria `001` `002` `003` y Contenedor `2` tiene 2 items correlativo `001` `002`

```
$query           = "SELECT MAX(nro_correlative) FROM CC_Despacho WHERE OP ='$op'";
$result          = mysqli_query($ConexionMYSQL, $query);
$row             = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$nro_correlative = $row[0] + 1;
$nro_correlative = '' . $nro_correlative;
$nro_correlative = str_pad($nro_correlative, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

En caso que yo elimine del Contenedor `1` el correlativo `002`, y si intento agregar otro item me gustaria poder agregar con el correlativo `002` no con el `004` (actualmente obtengo el mayor+1 si agrego uno nuevo).

He estado buscando utilizar ajax para obtener un array de mis correlativos  y verificar si hay un salto entre ese array pero no me ha resulado.

Espero haberme explicado bien. Saludos.

Comment: Cuando elimines un correlativo es necesario que actualices los valores de 'nro_correlative' en tu base de datos, de otra forma no estás reflejando ese cambio en la bd.

Comment: @MarioL lo estaba haciendo asi pero lo que ocurre que antes se imprimen unas boletas y actualizo los datos esta boleta queda con el correlativo erroneo.

Comment: Puedes mantener una tabla de número de correlativos 'disponibles', y vas tomando de ahí los valores. Al generarlo lo guardas en la bd, y lo marcas como 'utilizado', cuando lo elimines lo marcas como 'libre'. Al momento de generar uno nuevo, vas a buscar el primero libre en esa tabla de disponibles, y si no hay libres, creas uno y luego lo cargás.